# Get filenames sorted by mtime

Tags: linux, bash, awk, find

How to get file names sorted by the modification timestamp descending?

I should add that file names may potentially contain any special character except `\0`.

Here is what I got so far. The loop that gets file name and its mtime, however it is unsorted:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' fname; do
  read -r -d '' mtime
done < <(find . -maxdepth 3 -printf '%p\0%T@\0')
```

Comment: Why not `ls -rt --full-time` ? This places the oldest at the head. `ls -t --full-time` places the most recently modified at the head.

Comment: @JRFerguson I actually use `find` with the `-maxdepth 3` option and I do not think `ls` can do the same.

Comment: Oops, I missed the fact that you wanted to descend subdirectories. ENOCOFFEE ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reorder your find printf, it becomes esay to sort:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -printf '%T@ :: %p\0'|\
sort -zrn |\
sed -z 's/^[0-9.]* :: //' |\
xargs -0 -n1 echo
```

The `sed` and `xargs` lines are just examples of stripping out the mtime and then doing something with the filenames.

Comment: Brilliant! I used it with a change. After sorting I made sed replace ` :: ` with `\0` and then I sent the output to the original while loop.

Comment: for future searches: the relevant sed for that is `sed -z 's/ :: /\x00/'`

Answer (score 0):

For files within the same folder, this will do:

```
$ ls -t
```

If you want to cross a tree, one of these will do depending on your variant of Linux (stat command has different syntaxes):

$ find . -type f -exec stat -c '%Y %n' {} \; | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f2-

Or:

$ find . -type f -exec stat -f '%m %N' {} \; | sort -nr | cut -d' ' -f2-

I hope this helps.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: It seems that the simpler parsing of ls will be more difficult due to the expected special chars...

Comment: @Cyrus, I've changed '-f2' to '-f2-' to deal with files names having spaces. Apart from that, do you see scenarios where this would break?

Comment: @medalik It does not handle correctly a filename with a new line character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a list of files and timestamps, ordered by timestamp:

```
while IFS=: read mtime fname ; do
  echo "mtime = [$mtime] / fname = [$fname]"
done < <(find . -printf '%T@:%f\n' | sort -t:)
```

I've choosen a `:` as a delimiter as it is quite rare as a character for your filenames, being even prohibited in DOS/NTFS

With needs so stringent (filenames with `:` or `\n` as possible characters), 
to get what you need, you can try:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' mtime; do 
   read -r -d '' fname; 
   echo "[$mtime][$fname]"; 
done < <(find . -maxdepth 3 -printf '%T@\0%p\0' ) | sort -nr
```

Trying to solve the newlines embedded in the filenames:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' mtime; do
     read -r -d '' fname;
     printf "[%s][%s]\0" "$mtime" "$fname"; 
done < <(find . -maxdepth 3 -printf '%T@\0%p\0' ) \
| sort -nrz | tr \\0 \\n
```

Comment: Besides files with `:` in name it will not work with files that contain a new line character `\n` in their name.

Comment: If you just need to list your files, I've edited my previous answer.

Comment: It still does not display correctly for filenames with new lines. Sort handles each part of filename as separate entry then.

Comment: add `-z` option to sort to use \0 terminated rather than \n terminated input

Comment: Just adding `-z` would jumble the output together, as we didn't get any newline. The idea was great, though, thanks.I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -zn
```

and if you wanted to get just the filename newline-terminated after that then pipe it to awk to remove the timestamp and tab plus replace NUL with newline:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -zn | awk -v RS='\0' '{sub(/^[^\t]+\t/,"")}1'
```

Comment: How do I convert ````1545310882.0000000000```` back to ````Thu Dec 20 07:01:22 2018```` in the results.

Comment: Just use GNU awk for the awk part so you can simply call one of it's time functions, (e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%c",1545310882)}'` outputs 
`Thu, Dec 20, 2018  7:01:22 AM` - massage to suit), but you should really be asking this of the person who posted the answer you accepted.